# Google Sign In inside ReactJS Component

Tags: reactjs, google-api-js-client

I've created my component with complete functionality.

This component will only work if I add the following:
**/* global gapi */**

The following errors appear:

./src/GoogleAuth.js
  Line 13:  'gapi' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 16:  'gapi' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 21:  'gapi' is not defined  no-undef

What am I missing in my logic to be able to use the gapi without resorting to global? I am a beginner in JS and ReactJs so I apologize if I am missing a concept!

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'

class GoogleAuth extends Component {

componentDidMount() {
    let self = this;
    let scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
    scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptTag.src = "https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js";
    scriptTag.addEventListener('load', function (e) {

        gapi.load('auth2', () => {
            console.log("loaded gapi auth2!")
            // Retrieve the singleton for the GoogleAuth library and set up the client.
            gapi.auth2.init({
                client_id: 'XXXXapps.googleusercontent.com'
            });
        });

        gapi.signin2.render('g-signin2', {
            'class': 'g-signin2',
            'theme': 'dark',
            'width': 240,
            'height': 50,
            'longtitle': true,
            'theme': 'light',
            'onsuccess': this.onSignIn
        });
    });
    document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
}

onSignIn(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    console.log("token", googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token);
    console.log('ID: ' + profile.getId()); // Do not send to your backend! Use an ID token instead.
    console.log('Name: ' + profile.getName());
    console.log('Image URL: ' + profile.getImageUrl());
    console.log('Email: ' + profile.getEmail()); // This is null if the 'email' scope is not present.
}


render() {
    return (
        <div id="g-signin2" data-onsuccess={this.onSignIn} />
    );
  }
}

export default GoogleAuth;
```

Comment: You have no import for `gapi`...

Comment: so this is what I'm missing. How do I fill that gap? Since it's a third party library? Do I need to isolate it in a separate component and use Promises to resolve?

Comment: Use `/* global gapi */`